Firebase JS - Query like mySQL
i searched over and over but still not find an answer or a hint for following problem:
With SQL i can query like:
select * from table where X = Y and A != B ( in example)
Firebase is not SQL - i understand so far! But what if i have a structure like:
Users
   Id1
      Username: User 1
      Country: US
      Other: One
   Id2
      Username: User 2
      Country: CA
      Other: Two

   Id3
      Username: User 3
      Country: US
      Other: Three


How can I get only users with Country US?
And second, how can i get only users with Country = US and Other = Three?
What I have actually is the following code:
const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
get(child(dbRef, `users/`)).then((snapshot) => {
let userArray = [];
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
userArray.push(childSnapshot.val());

So can anyone give me a tip maybe with a code example?
